# Error message reading JSON file python - list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to load a JSON file.  Here is the code and file structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=columns)
for i,line in enumerate(open(json_dimName.json')):

    j = json.loads(line)

print j
```

`Output:
{u'dimensionalFacts': [{u'dimensions': [{u'dimName': u'us-gaap_BusinessAcquisitionAxis'}]}], u'stockSymbol': u'pfe', u'_id': {u'$oid': u'55400c1ae44f9e094c5833b2'}}`

I then try to read this into a pandas dataframe:
    `df.loc[i] = [j['dimensionalFacts']['dimensions'], j['stockSymbol']]`

This is the error message that I get:
    `list indices must be integers, not str`

I am new to python and programming so would greatly appreciate any help.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because each one of your j values has a list for the key:

```
{u'dimensionalFacts': [{u'dimensions': [{u'dimName': u'us-gaap_BusinessAcquisitionAxis'}]}]
```

What you want in this case is:

```
df.loc[i] = [j['dimensionalFacts'][0]['dimensions'], j['stockSymbol']]
```

This will grab the resulting dictionary from each j-value, since it seems there is only one dictionary per entry.

The error it gives is precisely the issue: you are trying to tell the program to seek position "dimensions", not an integer position, within a list.

Comment: Of course. If you like the answer and think it's the best one (there are other good answers here), please select it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`j['dimensionalFacts']` is a list; that's what the square brackets mean. You will need to index it using a number if you want to get to the dict inside it.

```
j['dimensionalFacts'][0]['dimensions']
```

Note that this will work for the example given, but more complex structures may require you to iterate over the list rather than assuming the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `j['dimensionalFacts']` is a list, so I guess what you want to do is:

```
df.loc[i] = j['dimensionalFacts'][0]['dimensions'], j['dimentionalFacts'][0]['stockSymbol']
```